# Evaluate $\int_0^{2 \pi} \sin \theta \cos^2 \theta \,d\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

The problem is to integrate $$\int_0^{2 \pi} \sin \theta \cos^2 \theta \,d\theta.$$
What I have tried is substituting $t := \cos \theta$, but the new limits of integration are equal to each other. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's perfectly valid. It simply means that the integral is zero.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a slick method that doesn't involve substitution (and still doesn't involve F.T.C.): The integrand is periodic with period $2 \pi$, because it is a product of periodic functions, so the value of the integral is the same over any interval of length $2 \pi$, including $[-\pi, \pi]$. But the integrand is odd (it is the product of an even function and an odd function), and the integrand of any odd function over an interval symmetric about the origin is zero, and so
$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \sin \theta \cos^2 \theta \, d\theta = 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that function $f\left(\theta\right)=\sin\theta\cos^{2}\left(\theta\right)$
satisfies $f\left(\theta+\pi\right)=-f\left(\theta\right)$ so that

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}f\left(\theta\right)d\theta=\int_{0}^{\pi}f\left(\theta\right)d\theta+\int_{0}^{\pi}f\left(\theta+\pi\right)d\theta=\int_{0}^{\pi}f\left(\theta\right)d\theta-\int_{0}^{\pi}f\left(\theta\right)d\theta=0$$